# Best way to delete "SetupAssistantPlugins" on Yosemite?

Tags: macos, plugins, third-party

I noticed that in the InternetAccounts folder in the System Library on my iMac's HD (late 2012) that there are a bunch of folders that contain ".iaplugins" from such unwanted companies such as Facebook, 126, 123, AOL, Google, LinkedIn, Flicker, Yahoo, and Twitter. I have no idea what these are for and have no desire to have my Mac associated with any of these "accounts" (there are a few for Apple accounts, such as iCloud, Mail, Notes, AddressBook, etc.). I assume I should leave the Apple plugins, but is it safe to delete the third-party plugins, and, if so, what is the best way?

Answer (score 1):

These aren't third-party plugins, but actually **first-party plugins** (created by Apple) for third-party services. It is **not recommended to delete these**, as with anything in the /System directory, however you can if you wish, using Finder or Terminal (authentication will be required).

Comment: Instead of deleting them, move them to another folder in case something breaks and you need them back.